# Which DB Does Google AppEngine Eclipse Plugin Uses

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Which database does the Google AppEngine Eclipse plugin use? How do I view local_db.bin file which is in war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated. Is it SQLLite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give [gae-data-viewer](http://code.google.com/p/gae-data-viewer/) a shot. That should let you view all of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The App Engine Java SDK uses its own in-memory representation, which it serializes to disk for persistence. An admin console data viewer/editor ought to be out in the next SDK release.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood local_db.bin uses internal format named "[protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)".